# Creating search facility in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to upgrade my search facility, at the moment I am listing all the skills available and once clicked it searches for handymens with that skill. Now I want to create a search box so once user inputs anything it will search and display all handymens with that skill once button is clicked. so for example 'p' would return 'Plumber'. But I am struggling hard with it so please help me, if any other files or databases need to be attached please let me know.

View:

```
    <h1>Here you can search</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='skill'/>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
     @foreach ($skills as $skill)
        <p>
            <a href="{{url('details/'.$skill->id)}}">{{$skill->skill}}</a>        
        </p>

    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
function search()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();
    return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
}
function details($skillId)
{
$skill = Skill::find($skillId);
$handymen = $skill->handymen;
$skill = Input::get('skill');
$result = Handyman::where('skills','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->get();
return view('layouts/details', ['skill' => $skill,'handymen' => $handymen]);
}
```

Handymen database:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymenTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('postcode');
        $table->string('town');
        $table->string('skills');


        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('handymen_job_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('job_id');
    });
    }
}
```

Skills table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSkillsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('skill');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('skills');
    }
}
```

Junction table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymanSkillTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('handyman_skill', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('handyman_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('skill_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('handyman_skill', function ($table) {
            $table->primary(['handyman_id', 'skill_id']);
            $table->foreign('handyman_id')->references('id')->on('handymen')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('skill_id')->references('id')->on('skills')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('handyman_skill');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but I'd recommend using something like ElasticSearch for your search services.
It works really great in my case where I have a few hundred thousand entries, and it's quite easy to set up.
Plus, there's a library called Elasticquent to make Elasticsearch easier to use in Laravel.

Comment: I am trying to keep things simple as that is what I was asked to do, without the use of such services